# log4j for MyBatis in a JUnit run configuration on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, log4j, mybatis

How can **log4j** be configured for **MyBatis** in a **JUnit** run configuration on **Eclipse**?

There are several such questions on SO and the internet. But, most of the suggestions don't seem to work for me.

Specifically, the following doesn't seem to work: (from the MyBatis logging [page](http://www.mybatis.org/core/logging.html))

1. `log4j-1.2.16.jar` is on my Eclipse's `Java Build Path Libraries` (under Maven Dependencies).
2. log4j.properties is on my `Run Configuration`. It's under VM arguments as: `-Dlog4j.configuration=C:\log4j.properties`
3. My log4j.properties file contains the below code.

---

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.logger.org.mybatis.example.BlogMapper=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
```

As per my understanding, things will work if I can keep the log4j.properties file on the Eclipse classpath. But, I'm **not sure if the run configuration VM arguments sets the classpath**.

### EDIT

If I force MyBatis to use log4j,

```
org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useLog4JLogging();
```

The following is output on the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: What do you get after these setting? no output or ??

Comment: @JintianDENG yes, I don't get any output on the console.

Comment: You set root logger to ERROR. May be you are checking logger.debug() or logger.info()..Did you check logger.error("test") is printing anything on console?

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k Actually, I'm not trying to print anything to the console myself. I'm interested in getting the logs from the MyBatis internal log factory. See [this](http://www.mybatis.org/core/logging.html) page.

Comment: May be you need to add log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis=DEBUG to your log4j.properties to get MyBatis internal log statements to get printed as your rootLogger is set to ERROR.

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k That unfortunately didn't help. According to [this](http://www.mybatis.org/core/logging.html) page, either `DEBUG` or `TRACE` can be used. Also see edit in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:
http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/log4j-for-MyBatis-in-a-JUnit-run-configuration-on-Eclipse-tp4026384p4026393.html

An alternate way to set the classpath is as described in the answer by @sivaprasadreddy.k

Answer (score 1):

Under VM arguments as: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\log4j.properties

Observe the prefix file:

-Siva